# Cypress: How to check if the element has a cropped text by text-overflow?

Tags: cypress

Is there a way to check if text was cropped by text-overflow?

CSS:

```css
.elem {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  ...
}
```

Sometimes element contain many text which overflowed and it's ending replace with '...'.

This won't work because actually there no '...' in element content it only visual:

```js
cy.get(elem).should('contain', '...')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ellipsis display depends on the element width.

Given this HTML

```html
<style>
  div {
    width: '30px';
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
<div>Really long textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
```

this will test the ellipsis at specified widths.

Testing the width is as expected will make a stronger test.

```js
cy.get('div').then($div => {
  expect($div.css('width').replace('px', '') - 30).to.be.lt(1)  // approx
})

cy.get('div').then($div => {
  const offsetWidth = $div[0].offsetWidth 
  const scrollWidth = $div[0].scrollWidth
  const isEllipsisActive = offsetWidth < scrollWidth
  expect(isEllipsisActive).to.eq(true)                 // ✅ passes
})

cy.get('div').invoke('css', 'width', '500px')          // widen the element

cy.get('div').then($div => {
  expect($div.css('width').replace('px', '') - 500).to.be.lt(1)  // approx
})

cy.get('div').then($div => {
  const offsetWidth = $div[0].offsetWidth 
  const scrollWidth = $div[0].scrollWidth
  const isEllipsisActive = offsetWidth < scrollWidth
  expect(isEllipsisActive).to.eq(false)                // ✅ passes
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make [CSS assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#CSS) to check the element has `text-overflow`.

```
cy.get(elem).should('have.css', 'text-overflow', 'ellipsis')
```

Comment: To add on - JQuery will always return the full text and not the truncated text, so as far as I can tell there is no way to use Cypress to get the truncated text.

Comment: cy.get(elem).should('have.css', 'text-overflow', 'ellipsis') - this css property already exist on element, even when element not truncated, so this one not work too(